# Reverse an explicit assignment of _ in python?

Tags: python

In python, if I create a local variable _ (underscore) and assign it to something:

```
_ = 3
```

Is it possible to reverse that assignment to regain usage of the underscore as the last returned output in the REPL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Use the `del` statement.

```
$ python
>>> _ = 3
>>> _
3
>>> 5
5
>>> _
3
>>> del _
>>> 6
6
>>> _
6
```